# Another connection within the try

Tags: php, pdo

Good afternoon everyone, I have a doubt.

I have a SELECT with PDO. More must be done within another SELECT WHILE to get data for that select, giving it more

Error (Error: There Is Already an active transaction).

If anyone can help me be grateful.

Example code.

```
try{
     $this->conex->beginTransaction();
     $query = $this->conex->prepare("SELECT idUser FROM usuario WHERE id = :id ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT $pagin, $paginaF");
     $query->bindParam(":id", $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 20); 
     $query->execute();
     while ($lista = $query->fetch()){
       $idUser = $lista['idUser'];
       echo "<div id='avatar'>"box::avatar($idUser)."</div>"
     }    
//Here he works out of WHILE. Inside it does not work...
echo box::avatar($idUser);
$this->conex->commit();
}catch (PDOException $ex) {
     echo "Erro: " . $ex->getMessage();
}

public function avatar($idUser){
     $idUser = (int) $idUser;
     $query = $this->conex->prepare("SELECT avatar FROM login WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1");
     $query->bindParam(":id", $idUser, PDO::PARAM_INT, 20);
     $query->execute();
     while ($avatar = $query->fetch()){
         $avatar = $avatar['avatar'];
     }
  return $avatar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the cursor before calling for a new transaction.
Besides, may I ask why are you creating transactions since you're only doing simple **select**s?

Comment: How can I get for not giving this error? Are you saying that does not need beginTransaction in SELECT? beginTransaction use in what order?

Comment: indeed, you can't nest transaction. Just close the cursor and it will work. But as I said, why are you using transactions for selects? Just don't imho. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Nested Transactions are not possible (as mentioned by the error message). In the first line, you start one transaction. Within the loop, you call `avatar()`, that starts another transaction, which fails, because there is already one.

However, for `SELECT`-Queries you dont need transactions at all. Just omit it.
You may also think about `JOIN`, so you can handle all in just one Query (and then transactions are really useless).

Comment: To join in this query would look like? Pera ai, plus the id not the same that I have been accessing the table (User) to bring another id. to access the table (login) have to do this in join?

Answer (score 0):

May not be an answer to the problem for now but this line :

```
echo "<div id="avatar">".$box = box::avatar($id)."</div>"
```

is full of errors.

1. `"` aren't escaped.
2. no `;` at the end.
3. You're trying to give a value to a variable inside an `echo`. This'll throw an error.

---

If you don't use the `avatar()` function elsewhere, you can do :

```
try{
 $this->conex->beginTransaction();
 $query = $this->conex->prepare("SELECT usuario.id as id, login.avatar as avatar FROM usuario, login WHERE usuario.id = :id and usuario.id ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT $pagin, $paginaF");
 $query->bindParam(":id", $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 20); 
 $query->execute();
 while ($lista = $query->fetch()){
   $id = $lista['id'];
   $avatar = $lista['avatar']
   echo '<div id="avatar">'.$avatar.'</div>';
 }    
}catch (PDOException $ex) {
 echo "Erro: " . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's not my code and it was just an example. I have now in hand to remove the doubt: D (d .= "<div id='avatar'>. $ box = box:: avatar ($ id )."</ div>";)

Comment: @user628298 : it's still wrong. You shouldn't have `$box = box::avatar($id)` here. `box::avatar($id)` will suffice.

Comment: (usuario.id = :id and usuario.id) = id not the same. The id is different, so I'm accessing (usuario) after (login). Sorry for my english I'm from Brazil D

Comment: @user628298 : From your code, it's the same `$id`. In the `while` loop, you take the `id` from your first request and you pass it to the `avatar` function which uses it in the new request. Hence, both `id` are the same.

Comment: Yes, I messed up the example. I tried to do so also did not give more, and will not appear or an error. public function avatar($id2){
     $id2 = (int) $id2;
     $query = $this->conex->prepare("SELECT avatar FROM login WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1");
     $query->bindParam(":id", $id2, PDO::PARAM_INT, 20);
     $query->execute();
     while ($avatar = $query->fetch()){
         $avatar = $avatar['avatar'];
     }
  return $avatar;
}

Comment: @user628298 : it's still the same value even if you change your variable name you know ? :)

Comment: This I know :O, and just so you understand :), the names of my variables are not these. Do not worry :)

Comment: He's running out of WHILE 1 more time, when placed inside WHILE it does not work, which is where you have to work on. You know why that?